# VS Code Intellisense Not Working for Python gRPC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, grpc, intellisense, grpcio

Is there anything specific that needs to be done to get VS Code's intellisense working for classes auto-generated by the gRPC compiler in Python? I ran the compile command:

`python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../pb --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../pb/demo.proto`

and then imported the generated class. When I'm trying to access the `request` object in one of the methods, autocompletion doesn't work and I'm unable to see the properties of the incoming request which makes development very tedious as I keep having to switch back to the proto file to check the names of properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Python Interpreter path.
To select a specific environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_work-with-python-interpreters

Comment: confirmed that the Python interpreter is pointing to the correct virtualenv and running ```pip list``` in the virtualenv shows ```grpcio```.